# What does "optional operation" mean in Javadoc of for example Set#add(E)?

Tags: java, set, javadoc

When in the java documentation for [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) it says in the specification of a method `Optional Operation` e.g. (emphasis by me)

> add(E e)
>             Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present **(optional operation)**.

What does the optional mean here?

That if I use a JVM other than SUN/Oracle, this operation may not be provided by that implementation of Java?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Set` is an interface. Classes implementing that interface do not necessarily need to provide an implementation for an optional operation.

I think those optional operations go back to the general `Collection` interface where operations are made optional which do not make sense for *some* kinds of collections. E.g. `add` is an operation that isn't really useful on some kind of read-only collection. It's spelt out explicitly in the Javadoc so it becomes part of what all collection classes offer but someone using it knows that, given *some* collection they do not know exactly, it could be that the method just throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: I see what you mean.So it depends on the concrete class used in the program and not in the JVM, right?Strange because for `Set` the `add` is basic IMO

Comment: @user384706, if you have an `ImmutableSet`, then if makes sense for the operation to not exist. Not every collection is mutable (some may just defer to some other data source, for example, that might not be modifyable).

Comment: Class that does not implement this method should throw exception, e.g. `UnsupportedOperationException`. For example this is what Iterator.remove() of unmodifiable collection throws.

Comment: @AlexR, they *may, but are not required to*, throw an exception. That's a difference. (See Matt's answer below which quotes the relevant bit from the Javadoc)

Comment: Why not instead have a subinterface like `ReadWriteCollection` that contains operations like `add` that are only appropriate for that type of collection? Not sure if I'm missing something but that makes more sense to me.

Comment: I found the reasons for this design choice of using optional operations instead of more interfaces in [another question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/77897/why-were-java-collections-implemented-with-optional-methods-in-the-interface) and [this Java FAQ page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/collections/designfaq.html#1).

Answer (score 5):

From the [java.util.Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) documentation:

> The "destructive" methods contained in this interface, that is, the
>   methods that modify the collection on which they operate, are
>   specified to throw UnsupportedOperationException if this collection
>   does not support the operation. If this is the case, these methods
>   may, but are not required to, throw an UnsupportedOperationException
>   if the invocation would have no effect on the collection. For example,
>   invoking the addAll(Collection)  method on an unmodifiable collection
>   may, but is not required to, throw the exception if the collection to
>   be added is empty.

Note that many of the methods described there are *not* optional.

The Java Collections Framework is, arguably, not perfect;  this may be one of the imperfections rearing its (tiny) head.

Comment: So you mean it is a design issue.They just declared methods that could be useless on some subclasses and made the subclasses carry them anyway?But isn't `add` basic operation for a `Set`?

Comment: Oh, it gets worse with the database APIs, such as `RowSet` and `ResultSet` where having unsuported operations is (a) common and (b) even more a PITA ;)

Comment: @user384706 -- in a nutshell, yes.  And while `add` is an operation for a `Set`, it may not be for another implementation of `Collection`.  Could they have done better?  Maybe, but software is hard and who knows what other constraints they were under.  I almost certainly would have done a worse job!!

Comment: @user384706 Actually, non-mutable sets are a completely normal thing to want in some contexts (for example, as mathematical objects). The alternative would be to have different interfaces like Set (immutable) and MutableSet (which would be a subinterface of this), and this distinction for the whole collection interface hierarchy. And then let's have some collections which support removal but not adding or the other way around. They decided on these *optional operations* instead.

Answer (score 2):

That an interface method is specified as *optional* in the JavaDoc means that classes implementing this interface does not necessarily have to implement that method. Instead, they could for example, throw an exception.

More specifically, that an interface method is *optional* in the JavaDoc does not mean that it is implementation-specific behavior. Each concrete implementation of the class will specify whether it implements it or not. Looking at the [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add(E)) class it includes the add operation and it does not specify it as optional. Thus, every implementation of the Java library will have to include an implementation of this method for their `HashMap` class. The same goes for `TreeMap` etc.

The reason why it might make sense for this operation to be declared as *optional* is because some sets may be conceptually immutable, such as those returned by [Collections.unmodifiableSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableSet(java.util.Set))