# Optional method in Collection interface

Tags: java, collections, methods, option-type

What does "optional" mean in [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html) context?

```
public interface Collection<E> extends Iterable<E> 
{
 // Basic operations
   int size();
   boolean isEmpty();
   boolean contains(Object element);
 // optional
```

The last line comment "//optional": what does it mean? I tried to implement a Collection by implementing it `public class Col-implementation implements Collection` and it's not optional at all.

I need to implement all the methods, even the ones commented as "optional".
I am clearly not getting what they mean by "optional". Any insight about that?

Comment: Ehi Rollerball your question has already been asked here! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572643/optional-methods-in-java-interface?rq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must provide an implementation, but that implementation can throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Answer (score 4):

In this context `optional` means that not all `Collection<E>` may do something useful in the implementation. Although providing an implementation is indeed mandatory, it is OK to [throw an exception to indicate that the method is not implemented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html).