# Dealing with list "Optional operation"

Tags: java

I was looking the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set-int-E-) of List to find a method that allow replacement of a element ( *set(int, E)* ) and I saw that the method is "optional". I searched for a while and found this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572643/optional-methods-in-java-interface) with a great answer from Laurence Gonsalves.

But I still have a question, until now everytime I used any interface, I never expected that a implementation could throw an runtime exception (unless I used it wrong or if it was a bug in the implementation code), even though I had exception when accidently tried to add elements to an immutable List, I didn't realized what was going on.

My question is: if I have an API method that has a List (or some other interface) parameter that has to invoke "optional" operations on that object how should I proceed?

- Should I avoid using List, and use some implementation as parameter?
- Should I make a defensive copy of the list, modify it and return that
  list? (this could change the implementation used by the api client)

*I know that the need to change a list received as a parameter in a method is questionable, but it may be necessary*

Comment: Hi Jarrod. I believe this is not a duplicate question, I'm not asking why the operation is optional, I'm asking how to deal with it. I had linked another question in my own question that explain why it is optional, and as I said in the question I read it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java libraries themselves consistently answer both of your questions "no."  For example, the utility method [`Collections.shuffle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) accepts any `List`, and throws an exception if the `List` passed to it does not support the necessary operations.  In general, sticking with that behavior is consistent with the Java libraries and with predominant development practices: go ahead and use the `List` as if it were mutable, and if someone passes in a `List` not supporting the necessary operations, they'll get the exceptions they deserve.

Comment: Well, that makes sense, so I basically have to make clear in the method documentation that the list must be mutable?!

Comment: it's normal that for 'optional' operations the operation can be done another way - such as deleting and inserting instead of replacing an element. Possibly with significant performance penalties and possibly with unwanted side effects. You could consider catching the exception and doing the operation the 'backup' way. As long as you document what your method does in those cases, shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @DJClayworth I wouldn't expect that to be the common case -- usually I would expect that if there was another way to support the operation, even an inefficient one, that the implementation would go ahead and use that approach in the method.

Comment: @RafaelTeles: Yup, that's the way to do it.